# LinuxでGenymotionが起動できない

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, genymotion

Kali LinuxにてGenymotionのインストールを試みたのですが、実行できません。行ったコマンド上での操作はpastebinに載せておきます。
https://pastebin.com/cwMqUxn5

また`/root/.Genymobile/genymotion.log`も載せておきます。
https://pastebin.com/u0JAEuaP

実行環境は以下の通りです。

```
 # uname -a
 Linux kali 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Genymotionを起動したとき表示されるエラーはこの通りで、「Unable to start VirtualBox」というアラートと、「Virtualization engine not found.Plugin loading aborted」と表示されています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、Android StudioのAVD ManagerでもAndroidエミュレータ実行を試みておりましたが、KVMでの実行ができず断念していたので、そちらの解決方法が分かりそうであればそちらでも構いません。詳細な情報を記載致します。

以上よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ログを読むと `VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory` とあるので VirtualBox のセットアップが正常に完了してないように見受けられます。

また、 VirtualBox インストール時に次のメッセージが表示されてますので、指示にあるように、カーネルヘッダーのアップデートと、/sbin/vboxconfig コマンドをroot権限で実行をしてみてください。

> Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:
>
> apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
>   (The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
>    apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
>    /sbin/vboxconfig
>   as root.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox最新版のインストールで、エラーが解消されました。